# "Tranche" as synonym for "collection"

Tags: word-usage, etymology, historical-change

Recently there have been a *tranche* (:/) of [news articles](https://www.pbs.org/newshour/politics/federal-appeals-court-halts-special-master-review-of-trumps-mar-a-lago-documents) referring to a "tranche of documents" found in Donald Trump's possession. Most dictionaries, e.g.,  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tranche)

> - a division or portion of a pool or whole

define tranche as a portion of a greater whole, and more specifically reference its technical usage in connection with the issuance of bonds:

> - specifically: an issue of bonds derived from a pooling of like obligations (such as securitized mortgage debt) that is differentiated
>   from other issues especially by maturity or rate of return

None that I know of mention it being used as a synonym for an entire collection.

Did this new shift in meaning precede news of the Trump incident? The majority of results to a news [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tranche%20of%20documents%22&safe=active&biw=1440&bih=697&tbm=nws&oq=%22tranche%20of%20documents%22&sclient=gws-wiz-news) indicate its technical financial meaning is still the most prevalent.

Comment: The collection of documents that was found at Mar-A-Lago is just a portion of all the documents that Trump dealt with during his presidency.

Comment: We may be dealing with word inflation, where tranche means many, a bunch, a whole lot. Where *decimate* meant destroying 10%, it's now routinely applied to a wipeout of 100%.

Comment: It's more than just a collection; it's a group that appears together, subsequent to a previous group. The word *tranche* seems apt to me to refer to distinct groups appearing separated in time.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I seem to see "decimate" as "reduce to a much smaller number" so more like a reduction to 10% of the original rather than to 0% or the Roman meaning of to 90%. Meanwhile I would still expect *tranche* to mean part of a greater whole

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tranche) includes the inflated (broadened) definition << A tranche of things is a group of them. >>

Comment: @Jack Good point; I'm now thinking the news articles *may* be using "tranche" in accordance with a broadened meaning: "slice of any [stratified] collection related to an identifiable characteristic". In other words, not a random sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Dictionary definitions of 'tranche'***

*Tranche* has not been an anglicized word for all that long, and for much of its life in the language it has had a rather narrow area of application. *Merriam-Webster's Ninth Collegiate Dictionary* (1983) says that it first occurred in print as an English word in 1930:

> **tranche** *n* {F[rench] fr. O[ld] F[rench], fr. *trenchier*, *trancher* to cut} (1930) : a bond series issued for sale in a foreign country

The *Ninth Collegiate* is also the first edition of the *Collegiate Dictionary* series to include any entry for tranche, suggesting the word's limited penetration of the language in the years between 1930 and 1983, The *Tenth Collegiate* (1993) repeats the *Ninth Collegiate*'s definition of *tranche* verbatim, but the *Eleventh Collegiate* (2003) offers a strikingly different (and more detailed) take on the word:

> **tranche** *n* {F[rench], lit. slice, fr. O[ld] F[rench], fr. *trenchier*, *trancher* to cut} : a division or portion of a pool or whole; *specif* : an issue of bonds derived from a pooling of like obligations (as securitized mortgage debt) that is differentiated from other issues esp. by maturity or rate of return

That definition has almost nothing in common with the definition in the *Ninth* and *Tenth Collegiates* beyond being related to bonds. It sounds as though a specialist in financial instruments got hold of the people at Merriam-Webster at some point between 1993 and 2003 and told them that their definition of *tranche* was either out of date or completely off the mark from the get-go.

In any event, although the 2003 definition starts with a generalized presentation of what *tranche* means ("a division or portion of a pool or whole"), it then dives into a specific meaning that is even more technical than the the 1983/1993 definition and certainly no less focused on usage within the financial sector. If MW's goal in formulating the first nine words of the definition was to expand the field of things that *tranche* can encompass, it shouldn't have followed that portion of the definition with "specif[ically]," since the specific meaning that follows whittles the broad opening phrase down to a very narrow financial application. A better option would have been to post the general meaning as one definition and to offer the finance meaning as a second, separate meaning rather than as a continuation or clarification of the general meaning.

Jonathon Green, *Dictionary of Jargon* (1987) offers two definitions of the term, both of them tagged as finance jargon:

> **tranche 1.** *n* {*Finance*} an instalment of a loan. **2.** {*Finance*} a block of bonds or government stock.

These two definitions are distinct from the two that Merriam-Webster put forward before and after Green's *Dictionary of Jargon* came out.

Although [Merriam-Webster Online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tranche) still adheres to the *Eleventh Collegiate*'s definition of *tranche* published in the twenty years ago, it has pushed the word's origin in English back to "the late 19th century" and added some commentary about the word's meaning in finance:

> In French, *tranche* means "slice." Cutting deeper into the word's etymology, we find the Old French word *trancer*, meaning "to cut." *Tranche* emerged in the English language in the late 19th century to describe financial appropriations. Today, it is often used specifically of an issue of bonds that is differentiated from other issues by such factors as maturity or rate of return. Another use of the French word *tranche* is in the French phrase *une tranche de vie*, meaning "a cross section of life." That phrase was coined by the dramatist Jean Jullien (1854-1919), who advocated naturalism in the theater.

This discussion ignores the fact that many people are familiar with *tranche* in the context of phrases such as "a tranche of ballots" or "a tranche of documents" (as the posted question here notes). To its credit, MW Online cites multiple examples of such usage in a section titled "Recent Examples on the Web," including "a new tranche of Russian rank and file forces," "another batch of 75,000 votes, a tranche that provided enough information," "the first tranche of aid," and "one more tranche of assistance"; to its discredit, MW Online makes no attempt to update its definitions to reflect this generalized usage of the word or to identify when the term first began to appear outside the world of finance. And when it says "Recent," the site means very recent: all of the examples it provides (many of which are duplicates from different news outlets) are from no longer ago than October 25, 2022.

---

***Early real-world instances of 'tranche' used in a nonfinancial sense***

I have never heard *tranche* used in conversation in a financial context (probably because I don't spend much time around the Wombats of Wall Street). On the other hand, I recall encountering *tranche* in its generalized sense of "batch" more than once in the years before Donald Trump became a U.S. president. My most vivid memory is of *tranche* appearing in the context of a stolen document file dump conducted by WikiLeaks, LulzSec, or some similar entity. As noted below, such dumps go back to 2010 at least.

However, nonfinancial use of *tranche* in English is significantly older than that. A search of the Elephind newspaper database turns up matches from as early as 1991. From "[First Phase of Sanctions Against South Africa Could Be Lifted Soon: 100 Prisoners Key to Bans](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/122382230?searchTerm=tranche)," in the *Canberra [Australia] Times* (September 5, 1991):

> Australia could be ready to lift bans on air links and "people links with South Africa after next week's Commonwealth foreign ministers' meeting in New Delhi, the Minister for Foreign Affairs. Senator Gareth Evans, said yesterday.
>
> ...
>
> Sporting contacts were part of the "people" sanctions but the Commonwealth decided in February to individually approve links with South African sporting organisations which met nonracial criteria.
>
> "I hope enough progress has been made on the prisoners and exiles issue to allow the recommendation of the lifting of the first **tranche** of sanctions [at New Delhi]," Senator Evans told a Senate committee examining foreign affairs expenditure.

International sanctions against governments are frequently economic, but the ones that Australia imposed on South Africa in this case were divided into two "tranches"—the first involving sanctions against South African travel, individuals and teams, and the second involving "financial and economic links." So the "first tranche of sanctions that Senator Evans refers to here is explicitly not "financial and economic."

From "[Fightback: Govt Cuts 'on Hold'](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/126962480?searchTerm=tranche)" in the *Canberra [Australia] Times* (December 15, 1992):

> The proposal to delay a section of the initial **tranche** of spending cuts is being framed to stimulate the economy. If adopted, it would be a significant change of direction and contrasts with Dr Hewson's criticism of stimulatory moves recently in Parliament.

Although "spending cuts" are certainly "finance-adjacent," they are nothing like the financial instruments that tranche traditionally referred to in financial jargon. This example is useful because it (like the previous example) shows tranche migrating from a strictly financial milieu to a political one.

From "[Indirect Bias to Be Target of New Rules](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/118194063?searchTerm=tranche)," in the *Canberra [Australia] Times* (July 29, 1994):

> Changes [to the Sex Discrimination Act of 1984] which Mr Keating is due to announce are the second **tranche** of amendments forming the Government's response to the 1992 Half Way to Equal report by the House of Representatives' Legal and Constitutional Affairs Committee.

Here the use of *tranche* arises in the context of civil right legislation—political and not especially financial.

So far, all three instances have come from Canberra, as do several others from later in the 1990s that I will not reproduce in this answer. The U.S. gets on the bandwagon in 1997. From Peter Denman, "[Ancient Forms and Contemporary Poetry](https://newspapers.bc.edu/cgi-bin/bostonsh?a=d&d=irishliterary19970901-01.2.4&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-tranche------)," in the *[Boston, Massachusetts] Irish Literary Supplement* (Fall 1997):

> For thirty years, a whole generation of Irish schoolchildren grew up knowing [Thomas] Kinsella—indeed, knowing all contemporary Irish poetry—by “Another September” and “Mirror in February,” the two poems included in the secondary school course for the Leaving Certificate. But what are the poems which will sum up the younger contemporaries, those born after 1940? It seems as if there is less emphasis on a signature poem emerging as representative of a writer. This is not to state that the younger writers are writing inferior poems but rather than they are read and apprehended differently. The anthology pieces no longer define an attitude to a **tranche** of poets. The anthologies that come out now are illustrative and explicationary rather than introductory and programmatic.

I think we can all agree that few things are less finance-related than a tranche of poets. The *Irish Literary Supplement* was a publication of the Irish Studies Program at Boston College.

And from Ben Wheeler, "[Vacations of the Guilty](https://spectatorarchive.library.columbia.edu/cgi-bin/columbia?a=d&d=cs20001012-01.2.21&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-tranche------)" in the *[New York] Columbia Daily Spectator* (October 12, 2000):

> Worse yet, the Clinton administration admitted the United States was a prime architect of the Chilean coup that brought Pinochet to power [0n September 11, 1973]in the first place. On June 30, 1999, the government agreed to declassify 20,000 pages of United States documents relating to Pinochet. Called "Human Rights in Chile: **Tranche** One," the release revealed many long-hidden secrets. Not only did we help organize Augusto's coup, it seems that we kept the cash flowing to the regime long after we knew it was the hemisphere's most accomplished human rights violator.

This may be the start of official U.S. government use of *tranche* to mean batch or partial collection or compilation. The usage is again unrelated to finance. It also anticipates the most common nonfinancial sense in which *tranche* is used today. The last example that I will cite here involves a Wikileaks dump from 2010; this may be the instance that I remember as my first encounter with *tranche*. From Jonathan Landay, "[New WikiLeaks Documents Show Calls for Attack on Iran](https://dks.library.kent.edu/cgi-bin/kentstate?a=d&d=dks20101130-01.2.24&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-tranche------)," in the *[Kent, Ohio] Daily Kent Stater* (November 30, 2010):

> The first **tranche** of documents, released by WikiLeaks, the whistle-blowing website, didn't contain any explosive revelations, although a cable outlining U.S. efforts to persuade China to stop commercial air shipments of North Korean missile parts to Iran via Beijing appeared to divulge a top-secret U.S. intelligence operation.

This is the full-blown "tranche of documents" usage that many of us are familiar with today. Although it appears in a college newspaper, the story was written for McClatchy Newspapers, at the time the second largest newspaper chain in the United States.

---

***Discussion***

The application of *tranche* to nonfinancial settings seems to be an instance of what Wilson Follett, [*Modern American Usage*](https://books.google.com/books?id=KgVpvTpFgU8C&pg=PA227&dq=%22popularized+technicalities+The+title%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjp0rf6k_v7AhVvIDQIHbxrDWEQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22popularized%20technicalities%20The%20title%22&f=false) (1966)—like [Henry Fowler](https://books.google.com/books?id=C8dZAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA444&dq=%22popularized+technicalities%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjusfCUk_v7AhXMPn0KHeI0ALEQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22popularized%20technicalities%22&f=false) before him—disapprovingly calls a "popularized technicality":

> **popularized technicalities.** ... In our time what is technical is in high repute; what comes from the amateur is regarded as amateurish. Consequently many phrases have been borrowed from the sciences, the techniques, and the professions to adorn and lend expressiveness to ordinary prose. The choice and application of these words and phrases have naturally not been controlled by the experts; the transfer has been indeed amateurish, and examination shows that a good many of the new terms or replace simple words long in use.

Perhaps someone came across *tranche* used in its highly technical financial sense of a particular type of bond issue (albeit one whose precise characteristics Merriam-Webster couldn't nail down on its first try), and thought, "Why should I use the word *batch* or *bunch* when I could instead use *tranche*?" Or maybe someone who did understand the narrow financial meaning of the term thought, "Why shouldn't *tranche* apply to bundles of things besides financial instruments—government sanctions, say, or spending cuts, or statutory amendments or poets?" Language is always mutating, whatever Follett and Fowler might think of the alterations.

What I find most perplexing here is why Merriam-Webster still hasn't updated its definition of *tranche* to reflect the reality that for more than thirty years people have been using *tranche* in a way that isn't *specif* related to an issue of bonds of any kind, and that more and more people (especially reporters and government officials) use it interchangeably with *batch* when referring to documents, votes, equipment, or people.

One of the more forlorn discussions of *tranche* that I came across in my Elephind searches was this one from Nancy Ezzell, "[Petticoat Patter](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth220701/m1/20/zoom/?q=tranche&resolution=3&lat=2829&lon=1415)," in the *Canadian [Texas] Record* (October 2005):

> Words, their meanings, their origins and their usage have always been a special interest of mine.
>
> ...
>
> And try this one on for size..."**tranche**." It appeared in a recent news story and stumped me, as well as the dictionary at hand. Turns out to mean "a bond series issued for a foreign country." It seems unlikely that most of us will ever use "**tranche**" in our daily conversation, but if we need to, be aware that it is pronounced just the way it is spelled. Rhymes with "ranch" and everyone in the Texas Panhandle certainly knows that word.

Although she didn't quote the definition quite correctly, Ms. Ezzell was evidently relying on *Merriam-Webster's Ninth* or *Tenth Collegiate Dictionary* for her information about what *tranche* meant. I can only imagine her befuddlement if she were trying to apply that definition to an instance such as "Human Rights in Chile: Tranche One," which the U.S. government had released five years earlier.

Comment: I think that all your typically well-researched references use 'tranche' in a forced 'smaller subset of at least notionally countable elements' sense; Collins (qv) gives an even broader 'group' definition.

Comment: I think perhaps a "first tranche" might at first blush be a random sample of a whole, but on reflection might still be in keeping with the idea of "a slice of a stratified whole", in that the slice criterion is simply the ordinal number of its release by an entity.